# Нужна ли запятая после "услугами"?

Tags: запятая

Сочетание их с популярными, но дорогими услугами, позволяет...

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, так как для этого нет никаких причин (Сочетание...с услугами позволяет...)

Answer (score 0):

После последнего однородного члена предложения, присоединяемого противительным союзом *а, но, да (в значении «но»), однако, зато* и др. и не заканчивающего собой предложения, запятая не ставится:

*Они получили небольшую, но удобную квартиру.*

*Солнце садилось в море, а не в тучи и было при этом клюквенного цвета.*